# Symfony - UniqueEntity validation fails with exception "addConstraint() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint, array given"

Tags: php, validation, symfony

When I am trying to validate my user entity form after posting I am getting a

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata::addConstraint() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint, array given
```

It is true that it is a array as it is defined like this in validation.yml

```
Transplan\CoreBundle\Entity\User:
  constraints:
    \Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: { fields: [company, username], message: "Brugernavnet er allerede taget" }
```

But how do I get the validator to understand that this is how you specify constaints in yml according to http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

My form is created like this

```
$user = new User();
$createUserForm = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
   ->add('username', 'text')
   ->add('name', 'text')
   ->add('Opret', 'submit')
   ->getForm();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're missing the `-` in front of the constraint.

```
Transplan\CoreBundle\Entity\User:
    constraints:
        - \Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: [company, username]
```